# .htaccess with multiple rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to create an htaccess file with the following rules:

I want to redirect:

```
http://computingessentials.tk/episodes/6
```

To:

```
http://computingessentials.tk/episodes.php?id=6
```

Same applies with the remaining episode.php ids

Next, I want to redirect:

```
http://computingessentials.tk/episode.php?id=56
```

To:

```
http://computingessentials.tk/episode/56
```

Same applies with the remaining episode.php ids

And last but not the least, I want to remove all the `.php` extensions of the files.

Since I am farlynew to htaccess i don't really know how to get all of these in an htaccess.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your mod rewrite of apache is on and put these rules in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^episodes/([0-9]+)$ episodes.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: in the question there are both `episode` and `episodeS` so i'd change it to `RewriteRule ^episode(s)?/([0-9]+)$ episode$1.php?id=$2 [L]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 rules in your root .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+episodes\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /episodes/%1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^episodes/([^/.]+)/?$ /episodes.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```